# Android Studio doesn't ignore .gitignore files

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea

I've added some masks and files to gitignore by **Settings>Version Control>Ignored Files**:

[image]

However, when I try to submit a new commit, those files are not ignored:

[image]

And I'm not sure why... I remember using "Ignored Files" before (in the same manner), and it worked correctly. Can anyone what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Settings | Version Control | Ignored Files is not .gitignore, it's IntelliJ IDEA's own ignore mechanism, which works for any version control system.

This mechanism only works for ignoring unversioned files. If you have already added your .iml file to the version control, it will not ignore subsequent changes to that file.

Comment: So, how do I fix this? Remove those files from version control?

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to track changes to those files, you need to remove them from git.

Comment: But now, the deletion of files has created a commit, and now my local files will be deleted too when I try to download the latest commit. How can I avoid this?

Comment: On your local machine, you can use `git rm --cached` to create a commit that will delete the files from git but keep them in your working directory. On other machines, those files will be deleted when you pull the changes; that's how removing things from version control works.